# Topological property of preimage of map $f$ taking the coefficients of characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, polynomials, connectedness, path-connected

Suppose we define $f\colon \mathcal{M}(n \times n; \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^n$ by
\begin{align*}
A \mapsto (\alpha_{n-1}, \dots, \alpha_0),
\end{align*}
where $(\alpha_{n-1}, \dots, \alpha_0)$ are coefficients of characteristic polynomial $p_A(t) = \det(tI-A) = t^n + \alpha_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \dots + \alpha_0$. $f$ is clearly continuous.

I am wondering what does the preimage $f^{-1}(\beta)$ look like for a fixed $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^n$? In particular, if we take a connected set $E$, is the preimage $f^{-1}(E)$ connected? In general, one would not expect a continuous map to have this property but somehow my intuition keeps thinking this is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preimage of a point under $f$ is not connected in general.  For instance, let $n=2$ and let $(\alpha_1,\alpha_0)$ be such that $p(t)=t^2+\alpha_1 t+\alpha_0$ has no real roots.  Then any matrix $A$ such that $p_A(t)=p(t)$ has no real eigenvalues.  In particular, if $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the standard basis, then $Ae_1=ae_1+be_2$ for some $a$ and some $b\neq 0$.  This gives two nontrivial clopen subsets of $f^{-1}(\{(\alpha_1,\alpha_0)\})$: one on which $b>0$ and one on which $b<0$.  (Both of these subsets are nonempty because if you take $A$ in one subset and conjugate it by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, you get an element of the other subset.)

In general, if $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ corresponds to a squarefree polynomial, then any two matrices in $f^{-1}(\beta)$ are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ with the same eigenvalues and thus conjugate by an invertible matrix.  Thus $f^{-1}(\beta)$ is a continuous image of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, and so has at most two connected components.  If the polynomial corresponding to $\beta$ has a real root, then any element $A$ of $f^{-1}(\beta)$ has a real eigenvector.  Letting $B$ be the map that negates this real eigenvector but is the identity on the other eigenspaces of $A$, we have $\det B=-1$ and $BAB^{-1}=A$.  This means that the two components of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ acting by conjugation on $A$ actually have the same image, and so $f^{-1}(\beta)$ is connected.  In general, though, as the example above shows, $f^{-1}(\beta)$ may have two components.

More generally, there is a section $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ of $f$ taking a polynomial to its companion matrix.  If $E$ consists of squarefree polynomials, then every matrix in $f^{-1}(E)$ is conjugate to a matrix in $g(E)$, and so $f^{-1}(E)$ is the image of $g(E)$ under the conjugation action of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.  If $E$ is connected, this means $f^{-1}(E)$ has at most two connected components, one for each component of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.  That is, one component is the set of matrices conjugate to an element of $g(E)$ by a matrix of positive determinant and one component is those conjugate to an element of $g(E)$ by a matrix of negative determinant, unless these two sets happen to actually just form a single connected set.  If any element $\beta\in E$ has a real root, then the two sets will overlap in $f^{-1}(\beta)$ as above, and so $f^{-1}(E)$ will have only one component.

(For polynomials that are not squarefree, there are multiple different conjugacy classes of matrices in $f^{-1}(\beta)$, since you can have non-diagonalizable matrices.  I believe that the non-diagonalizable matrices should always accumulate at diagonalizable matrices so $f^{-1}(\beta)$ still has at most two components, but I have not checked the details.  I have also not checked whether the two components of $f^{-1}(\beta)$ always are distinct if the polynomial has no real roots, but I suspect they are.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably we can deduce the property for $f^{-1}(E)$ from your answer but I don't see how. Could you give some elaboration on $f^{-1}(E)$ for a connected $E \subset \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Well, sometimes it's connected and sometimes it isn't, since in particular $E$ could be a singleton.  I may add more discussion later.

Comment: That is true. The interesting part is if $E$ is not a singleton and contains some open ball. Also I am having trouble to follow the part $f^{-1}(\beta)$ is connected when having a real root.

Comment: Well, the set of all $\beta=(\alpha_1,\alpha_0)$ as in my first example form an open set $E$, and the argument still applies when you take the entire preimage $f^{-1}(E)$ to find that it is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks so much for your amazing answer. But I could not follow "any element of $f^{-1}(\beta)$ has a real eigenvector and so commutes with a negative-determinant invertible matrix which negates that eigenvector, so the two components of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ map to the same component of $f^{-1}(\beta)$ and so $f^{-1}(\beta)$ is connected." Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: Also could you give a good reference for the materials contained in your answer? Thanks so much again.

Comment: I have added more detail on that part.  Unfortunately, I don't know a good reference.

Comment: Thanks so much. Basically I understand why the presence of a real eigenvector implies the preimage only has one component. But a small detail: why negating the corresponding eigenvector gives negative determinant? We can certainly choose the original one to have negative determinant. Is this by convention?

Comment: With respect to a basis of eigenvectors for $A$, the matrix $B$ is diagonal, with one diagonal entry being $-1$ (for the eigenvector it negates) and the others all being $1$.

Comment: Ah, I see I overlooked the way you choose $B$. Thanks again for your kindly replies.

Comment: Hi Eric. In your last comments, you mentioned if the polynomial is not squarefree, $f^{-1}(\beta)$ could still have two connected components. Does this follow from the simple fact: if we enumerate the possible Jordan blocks of the roots, these blocks are connected and the conjugacy classes of each Jordan form have at most two components. Could you comment on this thinking? Is there any complication I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's the rough idea, where "these blocks are connected" would mean that any matrix with one block structure can be connected to some matrix of any other block structure.  That's the part I haven't checked in detail.

Comment: Thanks. Does this work: for any $A_1 = S_1 J_1 S_1^{-1}$ and $A_2 = S_2 J_2 S_2^{-1}$ where $J_1, J_2$ has the same characteristic polynomial and $\det(S_1) > 0, \det(S_2) > 0$, we take a path $\gamma: [0,1] \to GL_n(\mathbb R)_+$ connecting $S_1, S_2$ and $\beta: t \mapsto (1-t)J_1 + tJ_2$, then take the path respecting the product $\text{Inv} \circ \gamma \times \beta \times \gamma$?

Comment: That doesn't work, since $\beta(t)$ need not have the same characteristic polynomial for all $t$ (the characteristic polynomial is not linear as a function of the matrix).  But you ought to be able to construct a different path explicitly that works.

Comment: I am a little confused. If we order the eigenvalues so that the diagonal elements of $J_1$ and $J_2$ agree, then $(1-t)J_1 + tJ_2$ is upper-triangular with eigenvalues unchanged. It seems the characteristic polynomial does not change. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, right, that does work.  I was vaguely imagining that the diagonal elements might not be lined up in the same order, but of course you can assume that they are.